# Angular routes, child routes and default routes

Tags: angular, module, single-page-application, router-outlet

I'm trying to use routes with modules...

**app.module**

```
  {
      path: '',
      component: AppComponent,
      children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      ]
  }
```

With import RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)

**dashboard.module**

```
  {
      path: '',
      component: DashboardComponent,
      children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'conta', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'conta', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/conta/conta.module#ContaModule' }
      ]
  }
```

With import RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)

**conta.module**

```
  {
      path: '',
      component: ContaComponent,
      children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'list', component: ContaListComponent }
      ]
  }
```

With import RouterModule.forChild(contaRoutes)

The idea is:

- Default route to app is dashboard
- Default route to dashboard is conta
- Default route to conta is contaList

When i run this code, app is loading **App > Conta > ContaList** and not **App > Dashboard > Conta > ContaList** how I wish.

I have inside my templates (App, Dashboard and Conta) a router-outlet.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the dashboard component you need to specify the path as dashboard like and same in conta module

```
{
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent,
      children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'conta', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'conta', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/conta/conta.module#ContaModule' }
      ]
  }


{
      path: 'conta',
      component: ContaComponent,
      children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'list', component: ContaListComponent }
      ]
  }
```

Comment: I try this before but i had an error
**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'list'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'list'**